Combinatorics about colored points on the plane
Problem: Suppose that each point on the plane $\Bbb R^2$ is colored by either blue or red color. Prove that there exists a half-equilateral triangle with the hypothenuse's length equal to 1 and all of its vertices are of the same color.
Additional definitions: For those of you who are not familiar with the definition of a half-equilateral, it is defined as the following: 1. Draw an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ and then 2. Cut the equilateral in half, for example drawing a line from $C$ to $H \in AB$ such that $\angle AHC = \angle BHC = 90 ^\circ$. By this construction and requirements from the problem, it is easy to see that $AC = 1, AH = 1/2, HC = \sqrt 3/2$ in the triangle $\triangle AHC$
My attempts: I try to find a configuration of equilateral combined with half-equilateral triangles and mainly try to use the Dirichlet theorem. However, this seems to be not working because as I try, I can always find a counterexample.
I hope someone can help me further understand the underlying combinatorics elements in this problem and help me to solve it. Thanks for any help in advance.

Presumably you mean a half-equilateral triangle all of one color?

We want to have in one color all this half-equilateral triangle ? Or the 3 vertices of this half-equilateral triangle ?

sorry for the mistake, i changed it back

What's Dirlichet's theorem? Dirlichet was a prolific mathematician, but I can't think of any theorems of his that involve equilateral triangles.

sorry for the mistakes, i'm not quite familiar with latex and this is my first or second time asking a question on stackexchange

the Dirichlet theorem is another way to call the pigeonhole principle. you can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Draw an equilateral triangle of side length 1. It has three vertices in two colours, so by the Pigeonhole Principle, one colour has at least two vertices.
So there are two points separated by a distance 1 which are the same colour. Without loss of generality, assume this colour is blue. Name the points A and D.
Now consider the regular hexagon ABCDEF.

ABD is a half-equilateral triangle (its hypothenuse of length 1 is AD, its side of length $\sqrt{3}/2$ is BD, and its side of length $1/2$ is AB). Since A and D are blue, either B is blue and ABD is a suitable triangle, or B is red.
Apply the same reasoning to C and E. If none of ABD, ACD, or AED are blue, then points B, C and E are red. In this case BCE is a triangle with all three vertices red. So either way there is a half-equilateral triangle whose hypothenuse's length is 1 with all three vertices the same colour.

Thanks, I couldn't have reasoned about the problem as this depth!
